# how to search list in list values in c#

Tags: c#, linq

I have to search field in which users can enter `Order Number` or `keyword`. keyword needs to search in `MemberOrderLineItem` `ItemName` value.

right now I am doing for Order number like this.

```
memberOrderInformationList = memberOrderInformationList
    .Where(x => x.OrderNumber.Contains(searchString))
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.OrderDate)
    .ToList();
```

But how to include `MemberOrderLineItem ItemName` value also?

```
public class MemberOrderInformation
{
    public string OrderNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime? OrderDate { get; set; }
    ...
    public List<MemberOrderLineItem> LineItems { get; set; }
    public MemberOrderInformation()
    {            
        LineItems = new List<MemberOrderLineItem>();        
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class MemberOrderLineItem
{
    public string OrderNumber { get; set; }
    public int OrderLineNumber { get; set; }
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: Do you want this: `var lineItems = memberOrderInformationList.SelectMany(x => x.LineItems).Where(x => x.OrderNumber.Contains(searchString)).ToList();`

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
memberOrderInformationList = memberOrderInformationList.Where(x=>x.OrderNumber.Contains(searchString)
|| x.LineItems.any(p => p.ItemName.Contains(searchString))
).OrderByDescending(x => x.OrderDate).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

if I am understanding the question correctly, you can try

```
memberOrderInformationList = 
memberOrderInformationList.Where(x=>x.OrderNumber.Contains(searchString) 
|| x.LineItems.FirstOrDefault(l => l.ItemName.Contains(searchString)) != null)
.OrderByDescending(x => x.OrderDate).ToList();
```

EDIT: Looking at the other answers, using `.Any()` opposed to `.FirstOrDefault`is a cleaner option, though both should work equally well.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
memberOrderInformationList = memberOrderInformationList.Where(x=>x.OrderNumber.Contains(searchString) 
                                                                || x.LineItems.Any(y=>y.ItemName.Contains(keyword)))
                                                       .OrderByDescending(x => x.OrderDate)
                                                       .ToList();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 memberOrderInformationList = memberOrderInformationList
                .Where(x => x.OrderNumber.Contains(searchString))
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.OrderDate)
                .Where(x=>x.LineItems.Any(x=>x.ItemName == "hej"))
                .ToList();
```